# Automatically filling some web forms?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine, and i was wondering if it is possible for me to auto fill some entries when i, well, redirect a user to a particular webpage?
To be more accurate, it would ease my job HUGELY if i could redirect a user to a webpage and automatically i can fill in most of the values pre-defined(Instead of having to type all these form fields myself, which is very time consuming. ).

I am new to programming so i am sorry if this sounds like a stupid question..

Comment: it depends on who host the web forms? if you host the web forms, then it is possible (via session or ..) otherwise, there is nothing gae can do. You need to create some browser extension.

Comment: Damn, well the form is on an external website, although one more thing, is it possible for me to SUBMIT the form to the website? Im asking this as i remember my udacity instructor auto submitting data to my very early website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes !

Each form input has a default value :

```
<input type="text" value="defaultValue" />
```

You'd just have to set this value to the desired default value and voilà !

---

In case you don't have direct access to the form's code, you could still fill them with default values using javascript (and jQuery to make things easier) with something like this :

`$("#inputId").val( "defaultValue" )`

Check this link for more information : http://www.ultramegatech.com/2009/10/default-form-values-jquery/

Comment: The OP didn't host the webform. I wonder how to execute the js code you provide?

Comment: As I don't have much more information, I supposed the webform is embedded in a page hosted by the OP.